# Trying to upload files to SharePoint list AngularJS and REST API

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

I have a SharePoint hosted html file with a form that I use to add a new list item to a SP list via the REST API. I am also reading data from the list using AngularJS for both reading and writing to list. In the code below I am trying to upload files to the list. Adding new list items work with no problem. The problem is uploading files. I think the form is closing without the files getting uploaded and I don't know how to pause it to wait for files to be uploaded. Or my code is not correctly uploading to SP. How should I be calling the uploading files function to upload the files to the list? Thank you.

This is what I have for the file upload element in the form. I am using the getFileData() to read the file names and display them in the div with id of files.

```
<form ng-submit="updateList()">
...
<div>
    <input type="file" class="form-control input-lg" name="attachments" id="attachments" multiple onchange="getFileData()">
</div> 
<div id="files"></div>
...
</form>
```

This is my controller code.

```
// BEGIN controller code
app.controller('supportController',
    function($scope, $http) {

    // BEGIN upload file code
    function uploadFile(listname, ID, file) {
        var formdigest = $scope.getFormDigest();

        var getFileBuffer = function(file) {
    
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            var reader = new FileReader();
    
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
            }
            reader.onerror = function(e) {
                deferred.reject(e.target.error);
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            return deferred.promise();
        };
    
        getFileBuffer(file).then(function(buffer) {
            alert(file.name);

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://.../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items(" + ID + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                method: 'POST',
                async: false,
                data: buffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": formdigest
    
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("file attached to the list item successfully...");
                },
                error: function(data) {
    
                    console.log("Error message: " + JSON.stringify(data.responseJSON.error));
                }
    
            });
    
        });
    
    }; // END file upload code 

     ...

    // BEGIN code to post a new entry to list
    $scope.updateList = function() {

        ...

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EU34SupportTracker')/items",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata' : {'type': 'SP.Data.EU34SupportTrackerListItem'},
                'Title': title,
                ...
                'Ticket_x0020_number': externaltt

            }),
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": formdigest
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("entry created successfully...");
                console.log(data.d.ID);
                // CALL UPLOAD FILE FUNCTION HERE
                $.When(uploadFile('EU34SupportTracker', data.d.ID, $("#attachments")[0].files[0])).then(location.reload());
                //location.reload();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                //console.log("#__REQUESTDIGEST".val());
                console.log("Error message: " + JSON.stringify(data.responseJSON.error));
            }
        });

       
        // close modal
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        location.reload();
      
    }; // END code to upload to list
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the **location.reload()** in sucess function is your problem since this is asynchronous execution you can rather use it has  **$.When(uploadfiles()).then(location.reload())**

you can also pass multiple ajax call as arguments to when, so this can also be done as

$.When($ajax1(), $.ajax2()).then(location.reaload());

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: I edited the code to show that new entry but unfortunately that did not work. But, thanks for the feedback.